# What is the problems with assigning reference types

Tags: c#, reference

I have the following sample.

```
namespace sample
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer C1 = new Customer();
            C1.ID = 100;
            C1.Name = "Mary";

            Customer C2 = C1;

            C2.Name = "Sandra";

            Console.WriteLine("C1.Name ={0} && C2.Name = {1}", C1.Name, C2.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

Why does the value of C1 changes when I assign a new value to C2. So in the end I get the following result: C1.Name =Sandra && C2.Name = Sandra

Comment: [Read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5057284/6695970) Jon Skeets' explanation of how reference types work.

Answer (score 2):

Because they're both references to the same object!

The opposite would be:

```
        Customer C1 = new Customer();
        C1.ID = 100;
        C1.Name = "Mary";

        // New instance stored on C2 reference
        // so now both are different references to also
        // different objects
        Customer C2 = new Customer(); 

        C2.Name = "Sandra";
```

Answer (score 0):

`C1` and `C2` are both *references* to the same instance of `Customer`.

`C2.Name = "Sandra";` changes the name of that customer via the reference `C2`

You *could* change `Customer` to a *value-type* by making it a `struct` rather than a `class`, or use the syntax `Customer C2 = new Customer();` to create a new `Customer` object.

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon you observe is called [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)). You have created references `C1` and `C2`. However, these do not refer to different objects, but one object, namely the one created by the constructor call `new Customer()`. Apparently you expect the statement

```
Customer C2 = C1;
```

to create a new customer *object* which then gets assigned the same values as `C1`. This is not the case - you create a new *reference* named `C2` which referes to the same object as `C1`.